# Android Native crash at /system/lib/libskia.so (Bitmap processing)

Tags: android, bitmap

I need help resolving a bug affecting an app on the play store.

Crash report on Play Developer Console:

1. This crash is only limited to certain **Android 4.4** devices
2. The crash can't be reproduced on an emulator
3. Stack trace occurs on native code (not Java), so it's really hard to see where this error is invoked
4. Research suggests it has something to do with **Bitmap processing**

I would really appreciate, if someone who has seen this before can shed some light.

Below is the crash report:

```html
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
UUID: ec6885dc-b4c9-43e8-8e07-d7e3ecb47b15
Build fingerprint: 'Sony/C6903/C6903:4.4.2/14.3.A.0.757/Cv1_jg:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 15177, tid: 15177, name: za.co.gometro >>> za.co.gometro <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000019
r0 00000001 r1 783a5010 r2 7744eb74 r3 0000000a
r4 00000001 r5 7744eb70 r6 00000001 r7 00000000
r8 784b1cd4 r9 00000001 sl 40bdaa90 fp be81e2fc
ip 40bdafe0 sp be81dee8 lr 40bd018d pc 404beb22 cpsr 00030030
d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
d4 0000000000000000 d5 0000000000000000
d6 0000000000000000 d7 437f00003f800000
d8 3f80000043d28000 d9 40c0000040c00000
d10 43d280004475c000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000019c00000438
d18 4010789444756f88 d19 408543d34475c1d2
d20 40d000004475e000 d21 445120004475e000
d22 4451b5794475c1d2 d23 44522f8844756f88
d24 bf29e7f85171d4e7 d25 3fd18bc451eed100
d26 3fd18bc451eed100 d27 bf56a47c07dc3459
d28 3febb67ae46c0827 d29 bfdffffffd0c5e81
d30 3fb33dc61a93ea8e d31 3ef99342e0ee5069
scr 60000013

backtrace:
#00 pc 000beb22 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPixelRef::getGenerationID() const+3)
#01 pc 0002b189 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#02 pc 0002b7a1 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#03 pc 00029cf9 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#04 pc 0001e43b /system/lib/libhwui.so
#05 pc 00021ad1 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#06 pc 00021d8f /system/lib/libhwui.so
#07 pc 00022371 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#08 pc 00017049 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#09 pc 000148ab /system/lib/libhwui.so
#10 pc 0001479f /system/lib/libhwui.so
#11 pc 0001d4cb /system/lib/libhwui.so
#12 pc 000671d9 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#13 pc 0002034c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#14 pc 00050fcf /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#15 pc 000297e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#16 pc 00030c6c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#17 pc 0002e304 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#18 pc 00063719 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
#19 pc 0006b6e7 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#20 pc 000297e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#21 pc 00030c6c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#22 pc 0002e304 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#23 pc 00063435 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#24 pc 0004cbb7 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#25 pc 0004da37 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#26 pc 0004e75b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
#27 pc 0000105b /system/bin/app_process
#28 pc 0000e4d3 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
#29 pc 00000d7c /system/bin/app_process

code around pc:
404beb00 6a816820 47884620 612560e5 f7e6a801 
404beb10 bd3ef949 6803b508 47886ad9 b510bd08 
404beb20 69834604 f7ffb913 61a0ff55 bd1069a0 
404beb30 61832300 23014770 3020f880 68034770 
404beb40 42526842 000ce881 e8904770 600b000c 
404beb50 604b4253 b5104770 1a10ee06 2a90ee06 
404beb60 7ac6eeb8 3a10ee01 0a02ed9d 23039c03 
404beb70 eb001822 eef80144 ed807ae6 eef87a00 
404beb80 edc00ac0 ed827a01 fb037a00 eef80004 
404beb90 edc21ac1 edc10a01 edc10a01 edc01a00 
404beba0 edc01a00 bd107a01 edddb530 9c047a03 
404bebb0 18256001 edc56042 60297a01 0144eb00 
404bebc0 7a01edc1 2103600b 0004fb01 60426003 
404bebd0 ed90bd30 eeb17a01 edd00a47 edc17a00 
404bebe0 ed817a01 47700a00 7a00edd0 0a67eeb1 
404bebf0 7a01ed90 7a00ed81 0a01ed81 ed904770 

code around lr:
40bd016c 1020f895 d0f92900 2025f894 0608f002 
40bd017c 2800b2f0 80e7f000 4620e7f0 ea0ef7e2 
40bd018c 60a84a73 612b69e3 61696a21 b002f85a 
40bd019c f7e24658 486ffca6 3000f85a a000f8d3 
40bd01ac f1ba9305 d1090f00 7031f44f eacaf7e1 
40bd01bc f7e74682 9905f885 a000f8c1 f7fe4658 
40bd01cc 4650f85a f7e66869 f894fe00 1e9a3024 
40bd01dc d8722a04 f002e8df 5c205c03 f640003f 
40bd01ec 210140f5 eb2cf7e1 f8946928 69692026 
40bd01fc 900069a3 0e62ea4f f2416920 91014201 
40bd020c f30efa23 46319202 f6419003 46401206 
40bd021c fee9f7ff e01c2301 40f5f640 1026f894 
40bd022c eb0ef7e1 3026f894 f248692a 69683163 
40bd023c 0c63ea4f 920069a3 90016922 f30cfa23 
40bd024c 46409102 46319203 1207f641 fecbf7ff 
40bd025c 732b2300 f894e038 f6401026 f7e140f5
```

Comment: What code are you running to code this crash?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as the stack trace doesn't show this. But I'm guessing it's either when I create a bitmap `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options)` or when I draw the bitmap in onDraw of a custom view `canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);` where `paint` is a Paint object with a bitmap shader using `Shader.TileMode.CLAMP` and the loaded bitmap. This is to allow rounded corners when drawing the bitmap