# Android Native crash at /system/lib/libskia.so

Tags: android, bitmap, crash

There's already been post about this here, no answer though: [Android Native crash at /system/lib/libskia.so (Bitmap processing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091282/android-native-crash-at-system-lib-libskia-so-bitmap-processing)

I too am having problems only with 4.4 phones but can't seem to resolve the problem. I also can't find much help online.

Some Context: I am working on a game (fairly basic mainly just draws rectangles except for the main character which requires a bitmap). The problem occurs when I start an activity to restart the game.

```
i = new Intent("com.walz.joltimate.Survival");
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Here is the log:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'lge/g3_vzw/g3:4.4.2/KVT49L.VS98512B/VS98512B.1414669625:user/release-keys'
Revision: '10'
pid: 17289, tid: 17289, name: timate.dodgeguy >>> com.walz.joltimate.dodgeguy <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
r0 00000000 r1 00000000 r2 416a9a98 r3 79722d48
r4 00000000 r5 416a9a98 r6 00000004 r7 6d649dc4
r8 bebfb2c8 r9 6d649dbc sl 416a9aa8 fp bebfb2dc
ip 40228740 sp bebfb2b0 lr 401f2b7f pc 404c3854 cpsr 600d0030
d0 0000019543cac000 d1 0000000043cac000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
d4 343bc000bd455fa1 d5 437b7e9040c00000
d6 bbef04213208c820 d7 c288000042000000
d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 00720064006e0061 d17 002e00640069006f
d18 002e006900750067 d19 0070007300690044
d20 004500790061006c d21 0074006e00650076
d22 006e006e006f0043 d23 0069007400630065
d24 0001000200020001 d25 0006000500040003
d26 0000000000000000 d27 0000000000000000
d28 3ff0000000000000 d29 0000000000000000
d30 0006000600060006 d31 0000000000000000
scr 60000012

backtrace:
#00 pc 000a6854 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkDevice::accessBitmap(bool)+5)
#01 pc 00078b7b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#02 pc 0002054c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#03 pc 0005132f /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#04 pc 000299e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#05 pc 00030f48 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#06 pc 0002e5e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#07 pc 00063af9 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
#08 pc 0006ba1f /system/lib/libdvm.so
#09 pc 000299e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#10 pc 00030f48 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#11 pc 0002e5e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#12 pc 00063815 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#13 pc 0004cf17 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#14 pc 0004e73f /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#15 pc 0004f497 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
#16 pc 0000109b /system/bin/app_process
#17 pc 0000e5cb /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
#18 pc 00000db0 /system/bin/app_process

code around pc:
404c3834 4604b538 b9336b83 f7e82004 4605ea3a 
404c3844 fcf9f00d 6ba063a5 b538bd38 4601460c 
404c3854 2b08f851 47986f53 b10c4605 ff6ef7ec 
404c3864 bd384628 41f0e92d 460d4610 461f2100 
404c3874 9e079c06 ffe9f7ff 4623463a 46019606 
404c3884 e8bd4628 f00241f0 e92dbfda 46994ff0 
404c3894 b0b7684b 460c4605 2b004690 80d4f000 
404c38a4 f7ec4608 4607ff50 f0402800 e08680cd 
404c38b4 2e009e40 2e04d052 8087f040 f89de04e 
404c38c4 2e06605c 80a9f040 2a009a0f 809ff040 
404c38d4 2701e0a3 21014620 f88d9406 9105101c 
404c38e4 fdccf7ec 98249a23 0302ebc8 b018f8d4 
404c38f4 0600ebc9 ea4f6920 f8cd0883 fb0ba060 
404c3904 9e058106 0901eb00 f88d4650 f7ec6064 
404c3914 9a15fdb5 9e409b16 22009202 464b9303 
404c3924 f8cd9812 9601b000 f7fd9914 a818f9a3 

code around lr:
401f2b5c b005ee04 b510bd00 b919460c fb1ff001 
401f2b6c bd104620 fdfcf001 edfcf7c8 f7c82100 
401f2b7c 69c0ee00 b510bd10 b919460c fb0ff001 
401f2b8c bd104620 fdecf001 edecf7c8 f7c82100 
401f2b9c 6a00edf0 b510bd10 b151460c fde0f001 
401f2bac ede0f7c8 f7c82100 e8bdede4 f0144010 
401f2bbc f001b805 4620faf4 b530bd10 b08b4615 
401f2bcc f44fb142 f7c57082 4629ef4e f7c64604 
401f2bdc e00defe4 f7c64668 f44fef50 f7c57082 
401f2bec 4669ef42 f7c64604 4668efd8 efdaf7c6 
401f2bfc b00b4620 0000bd30 461cb5f7 46154e10 
401f2c0c b1e2447e 681bb1db 6b1f4610 ed8cf7c8 
401f2c1c 46204601 462847b8 eda4f7c8 4620b178 
401f2c2c eda0f7c8 4807b158 58334669 33084628 
401f2c3c 0018e88d eda2f7c8 f7ff4668 bdfefc75 
401f2c4c 00034730 ffffff38 47f0e92d 8b02ed2d
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your issue looks related to this post at Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58515 It looks that the issues showing up in some 4.3 and many 4.4. You might want to update a device to Android 5, there were many changes to libskia library